# How to update a value in local SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

In my program I want the user to have the option to change the value (price in my example) in a local database, that I created.

I'm having a problem with it. The connection works fine and it debugs well and even shows the message that "saving ok", but it doesn't change at all in the database.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var con = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\sam\Desktop\hello\hello\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        try
        {
            myconnection.Open();     
            var query = string.Format("update DBTable set price='"+textBox2.Text+"' where ParamToCheck='"+comboBox5.Text+"'");
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("saved ok !!");     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The user can choose a string from the `combobox5` and change his price from `textBox2` by entering number - that what I want - but it doesn't change.

Comment: Does the query work if you run it directly in SSMS?

Comment: Are your table / column names really `DBTable` and `ParamToCheck`? 
Additionally: if price is not a varchar/nvarchar, there is no point in wrapping your value in quotes.

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows updated by the query. Your message box "saved ok" doesn't tell you the truth. Check with _int rowsUpdated = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();_ and then look at the value of rowsUpdated.

Comment: Further to what @ChrisF said, copy and paste the value of your query variable into SSMS and run it. It could do nothing and still not return an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone works fine now !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write SQL queries is through the use of parameters and with the correct datatype for each column. Concatenating strings as you do now is a secure recipe to fall into many types of errors. The simple one is a failure in correctly understanding your values by the database engine. The worst one is called [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) that could destroy your entire database.

```
var query = "update DBTable set price=@price where ParamToCheck=@prm";
using (SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(con))
using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection))
{
    try
    {

        myconnection.Open();     
        cm.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
        cm.Parameters.Add("@prm", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox5.Text;
        int rowsUpdated = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(rowsUpdated > 1)
             MessageBox.Show("saved ok !!");     
        else
             MessageBox.Show("No match for condition:" + comboBox5.Text);     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have simplified a lot your query text without using a concatenation of strings, instead there are two parameters placeholders that will be used by the database engine to complete your command. After that I have added two parameters of specific data type (decimal and nvarchar). These types should match your column's datatype for Price and ParamToCheck.